# Is it possible to boost Windows' sound volume to a higher limited value?

Tags: windows, audio, headphones

I often listen to [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm) with my headphones on, but sadly, some songs are recorded with a bit lower volume than the other. Even when maxing out all my audio settings, ***I want more***.

**Is there any way to get more volume using a third-party tool or another approach?**

Comment: You haven't got your headphones plugged into the line out, rather than headphone socket have you?

Comment: You do use the Volume knob, do you?

Comment: Yes, if the 'third-party tool' is an external amplfier. This seems to be the only way to get more than 100%.

Comment: This will almost certainly cause clipping, though and therefore sound distortion. And especially nice if you're listening to music and an exceptionally loud error ping pierces your eardrums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by installin [AC3 Boosting Software](http://ac3.software.informer.com/download-ac3-booster-plugin/) or codec tool.

Answer (score 4):

I found these solutions but they only seem to work with certain media players:

- http://www.srslabs.com/anniversary/hd_audio.html
- http://www.fxsound.com/dfx/index.php

Honestly, I think this is one of the things that end up worse than before, mainly because laptop speakers are inherently crappy and pumping them will make them sound, well, super-crappy. Just get a pair of [$10 stereo speakers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000R9AAJA), which is a way better and more permanent solution than anything you can do with software.

Comment: I love DFX! Just brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)  has the option to extent sound control. But  you should use last.fm plugin with VLC to do that.