# Boost maximum windows volume

Tags: windows, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to boost Windows' sound volume to a higher limited value?](https://superuser.com/questions/58788/is-it-possible-to-boost-windows-sound-volume-to-a-higher-limited-value)

Is it possible to boost maximum volume in Windows?

Not only for mp3s/videos, but system-wide.

For example, OS X has [Boom](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id415312377). I need something similar for Windows.

[image: Boom Image]

Windows 8, 64bit.

Comment: That question was in 2009. There are new operating systems(Windows 8), and AC3 Boosting Software is dead(its site is not working).

Comment: I don't see where you mentioned that you tried those programs in Windows 8, or that you wanted solutions specifically for Windows 8. Edit your question and tags to reflect this.